# filtering the words ending with "ed" or "ing" using haskell

Tags: haskell

hi am new to Haskell and functional programing..

i want to pass in the string and find the words ending with "ed" or "ing".

```
eg: if the string is "he is playing and he played well"
answer should be : playing, played
```

does anyone know how to do this using Haskell.

Comment: You probably want to use the functions `words`, `filter` and `isSuffixOf`. The first two are in the Prelude, the last one can be imported from `Data.List`.

Comment: is this your homework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build this using standard Haskell functions. Start by importing Data.List:

```
import Data.List
```

Use `isSuffixOf` to determine if one list ends with another. Below `endings` could be `["ed","ing"]` and `w` would be the word you're testing, such as `"played"`.

```
hasEnding endings w = any (`isSuffixOf` w) endings
```

Assuming you have split the string into a list of individual words (`ws` below), use `filter` to eliminate the words you don't want:

```
wordsWithEndings endings ws = filter (hasEnding endings) ws
```

Use `words` to get the list of words from the original string. Use `intercalculate` to join the filtered words back into the final comma-separated string (or leave this off if you want the result as a list of words). Use `.` to chain these functions together.

```
wordsEndingEdOrIng ws = intercalate ", " . wordsWithEndings ["ed","ing"] . words $ ws
```

And you're done.

```
wordsEndingEdOrIng "he is playing and he played well"
```

If you're typing into ghci, put `let` in front of each of the function definitions (all lines but the last one).

Answer (score 0):

```
contain w end = take (length end) (reverse w) == reverse end

findAll ends txt = filter (\w -> any (contain w) ends) (words txt)

main = getLine >>= print . findAll ["ing","ed"]
```

findAll :: [String] -> String -> [String]
findAll :: "endings" -> "your text" -> "right words"